# how to set hbase cluster's starting parameters

Tags: hbase, cluster-computing

how to set hbase cluster's starting parameters, such as:

RegionServer:

```
-Xms16g -Xmx16g -Xmn2g -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85
```

DataNode:

```
-Xms2g -Xmx2g
```

how to set this starting parameters? are they set in `hbase-env.sh` or `hbase-site.xml` before starting the hbase cluster?

i noticed that there is only a `maxheapsize` option in `hbase-env.sh`, then how to set other parameters? in detail, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would notice this is a HBASE_OPTS and HADOOP_OPTS setting in hbase-env.sh and hadoop-env.sh respectively, you can set the above in those files.

Comment: this is how my hbase-env.sh entry looks like :-
export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -ea -Xms24576m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=64m -XX:MaxNewSize=64m -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancy
Fraction=80"